# Generating MHTML from HTML

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, mhtml

I'm looking for a way of generating mhtml from a page in my asp.net web app.

I've seen this website and played with the code but i don't really want to use interop.cdo and interop.adodb. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnethtml2mht.aspx

Other than generating all the mhtml myself i'm a bit stumped....
Anyone got any clever ideas?

Comment: This is the ticket; Does 90% of what i need. [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx) Looks like it was written by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) man