# Asp.net how to convert HTML page to mht with .net?

Tags: html, mhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating MHTML from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925210/generating-mhtml-from-html)

I need to convert html page to mht format with c# .net
is there any .net library for this?
I need any lib whether its free or not

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnethtml2mht.aspx

Comment: no, in this code its adding things to the mht file then save it " oMhtCol.add(New mhtImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("/mhtml/images/myComputer.jpg")), "images/myComputer.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))" , i need to give it the URL and it gives back the mht file