# how to create mhtm using xml, xsl and the png files

Tags: .net, powershell, mhtml

I have a folder contains few images(.png files), one xsl file which is linked in xml file and few URLs which are present in xsl, and a xml file. Could anyone please let me know how to create mhtm file using the xml file using power shell or .net or vb script? 
(output: *The mhtm page should be opened with embedded images, urls and the content of the xsl and xml file.)

Comment: Praveen, welcome to StackOverflow. It is considered a good practice to give code that you have tried. Don't just ask questions on how to do something. People expect you to have tried something and then can help you by pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could adopt from this article by [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) on [converting any URL to a MHTML archive](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx) originally linked in this post on [Generating MHTML from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925210/generating-mhtml-from-html).